# style parent component using css

Tags: angular

So basically what I am trying to do is modify the CSS of an element belonging to the parent component. I have a link that is once clicked it routes to a new component which is a popup modal. I am trying to apply a background color, opacity etc....to the parent component. How can I achieve this?

[Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, click on the login button and you will see a popup appear and the background change.](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/jquery/login-box-modal-dialog-window/index.html)

login component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './app/login/login.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app/login/login.component.css' ]
})

export class LoginComponent {}
```

main component which routes to login component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-component',
    templateUrl: './app/main.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app/main.component.css' ],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent}
])

export class MainComponent {}
```

html portion of main.component.html that contains the link which routes to login.component.ts. How do I use css on this stylesheet to lets say do z-index, opacity etc.....from the login component?

```
<header>
    <h1>Budget Calculator</h1>
    <a id='login' [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
</header>
```

Comment: The example you give doesn't do what you asked - it simply creates new `<div id="mask">` and places it below login modal with `z-index`... You can do that too.

Comment: @Sasxa that is exactly what I do....sorry to confuse you with the popup modal....once the link is clicked it routes to a new component and then that component is shown.....I need to modify the parent component through css

Comment: @Sasxa I added some code to reduce the confusion.....

Comment: You can't style a parent with CSS. What might work is to add a style tag imperatively to `<head>` that targets the element you want to style.

Comment: @Gunter I thought inline styles was considered bad practice....but in the case of Angular 2 it is acceptable? I think this is a bad design....

Comment: Where did I write about inline styles? Inline styles are **not** bad practice. The Angular style guide suggests moving inline styles and templates to external files if they are more then 3 lines.

Comment: @Gunter you said to add a style tag to the head, I was thinking header. I am sorry....